# Filter messages before executing @RabbitListener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

How can I filter a message before is processed by a @RabbitListener annotated method ?

If the message is for. ex. is "duplicated" because contains an header with a determinate value I would like to return "ack" and skip processing. (skip the body of @RabbitListener method)

I tried to do it in a MessagePostProcessor (with addAfterReceivePostProcessors)  but cannot skip execution for ex. based on a message property (header).
This is the signature of MessageProcessor :

```
    Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException;
```

I would like to return an "ack" here so the message processing is skipped.

thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I think an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` is what you need to throw from your `MessagePostProcessor` impl.

See its javadocs:

```
/**
 * Exception for listener implementations used to indicate the
 * basic.reject will be sent with requeue=false in order to enable
 * features such as DLQ.
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 1.0.1
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException extends AmqpException {
```

And respective docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#exception-handling

Comment: AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException will send the message to DLQ, I don't want to send message to DLQ I would like to simply process and discard the message. ('ack' the message).